# Создание объектов напрямую в памяти процесса/Взаимодействие с консолью процесса из памяти

Tags: windows, память, процесс, движок

Допустим, имеется некоторое игровое приложение, которые было разработано сторонними разработчиками.

Хочу сделать приложение, которое будет анализировать чат `twitch.tv` и в самой игре создавать события. Например, в чатике запустилось какое-то голосование и по итогам этого голосования создались орды врагов. С парсингом чата проблем нету, так как там есть `API`.

Вот только проблема в том, что игры эти не имеют никакого внешнего `API` для взаимодействия с ними извне.

У меня были идеи воспользоваться программой `CheatEngine` для нахождения участков памяти в процессе, которые хранят нужные переменные, но как я понимаю, в таком случае я смогу менять только базовые показатели (Например, здоровье.), а создавать новые объекты я не смогу. А если изучать память приложения и пытаться найти конструкторы, то мне кажется, что это невыполнимо.

В некоторых играх есть великая и могучая консоль, которая обладает нужным функционалам, но возникает другая проблема- игровой процесс при ее активации замирает. Т.е даже, если я воспользуюсь `WinApi`, что бы активировать консоль и вбить команду автоматически, то трансляция превратится в слайд-шоу при большом кол-ве событий.

Может бы кто-нибудь подобным занимался и знает в какую сторону копать ?

Может можно отыскать в памяти процесса консоль и напрямую из стороннего процесса писать и выполнять команды?

На некоторых трансляциях `twitch.tv` я подобный интерактив видал в играх: Skyrim,Fallout 4, Half-Life 2, Darkest dungeon => кто-то как-то это делает, но в открытом доступе я ничего не нашел.

Comment: Может покопать в сторону, как подсунуть программе события мыши/клавиатуры? (т.е. эмулировать работу пользователя)

Comment: @avp, я думал об этом. Но тогда возникает проблема в том, что будет открываться на мгновение консоль и тормозить работу самой программы.

Comment: В принципе, наверное, можно было бы использовать технологию, которую использует отладчик, когда он приаатачивается к удаленной программе и приостанавливает ее выполнение, а мы можем вызывать в ней функции и менять переменные в памяти, а потом возбновить работу программы. Но, не думаю, что это можно успешно проделать (так, чтобы она не отвалила) с чужой программой.